# Detect if spotify track is 'explicit' via the apps api or web api

Tags: spotify

Is there any way to detect if a track in spotify is explicit via the apps api or the web api?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Web API does expose this data as of now.

[example JSON search](http://ws.spotify.com/search/1/track.json?q=fuck+you)

Answer (score 0):

The APIs do not currently expose this data.